# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: in AppleScript Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, applescript

Is there any way I can use the method below or something like this in AppleScript Obj-C?

```
NSString *request = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{query}"
                                                        withString:queryString];
```

Comment: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-06.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use text item delimiters

```
set theReplacementString to "-----"
set {theOriginal, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "{query}"}
set theParts to every text item of "{query}asd{query}sadsa{query}"
set text item delimiters to theReplacementString
set theResult to theParts as string
set text item delimiters to theOriginal
return theResult
```

gives you

```
"-----asd-----sadsa-----"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked:

```
set theText to "01 01 2005"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
set theTextItems to text items of theText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/ "
set theText to theTextItems as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
theText
```

Comment: The `text item delimiters` property is no longer global, so it's not usually necessary to restore it. The `AppleScript's` part isn't needed in the default scope either.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, you can convert the Cocoa method and use the equivalent ASOC statement (see the [AppleScriptObjC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ScriptingAutomation/RN-AppleScriptObjC/_index.html)):

```
set urlString to current application's NSString's stringWithString_("{query}asd{query}sadsa{query}") -- create an NSString to use with the Cocoa method
set queryString to "-----" -- the replacement string
set request to urlString's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString_withString_("{query}", queryString) -- the NSString method in ASOC
display dialog request as text
```